# Why doesn't the group animation work for me?

Tags: css, animation, svg, transform

I have svg (from undraw edited in figma) with groups selected by id and I would like to have animation in css on these groups.

But I set animation for group with id head and it doesn't work (The head should tilt, but the image doesn't move at all).

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for your reply!

```css
#head{
  animation: head 1s ease infinite alternate;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

@keyframes head{
  from{
    transform: rotateZ('-10deg');
  }
  to{
    transform: rotateZ('10deg');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-animation">
      <svg width="600" height="523" viewBox="0 0 600 523" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="undraw_developer_activity_re_39tg 1" clip-path="url(#clip0_3_67)">
// Lots of other vectors
        <g id="head">
        <path id="ab6171fa-7d69-4734-b81c-8dff60f9761b" d="M199.507 172.87C226.126 172.87 247.704 151.292 247.704 124.674C247.704 98.0553 226.126 76.4769 199.507 76.4769C172.889 76.4769 151.311 98.0553 151.311 124.674C151.311 151.292 172.889 172.87 199.507 172.87Z" fill="#FFB6B6"/>
        <path id="bf427902-b9bf-4946-b5d7-5c1c7e04535e" d="M241.715 89.3366C241.715 89.3366 254.32 65.2383 226.587 63.0475C226.587 63.0475 202.945 41.6007 178.847 59.1267C178.847 59.1267 165.702 59.1267 158.514 74.0013C158.514 74.0013 148.176 70.0805 145.904 80.5736C145.904 80.5736 138.339 102.481 145.904 122.198C153.469 141.915 155.981 144.106 155.981 144.106C155.981 144.106 143.551 102.768 173.808 100.577C204.064 98.3866 237.923 79.4782 240.444 103.577C242.966 127.675 246.76 133.612 246.76 133.612C246.76 133.612 270.709 99.1951 241.715 89.3366Z" fill="#2F2E41"/>
        <path id="Vector_42" d="M257.955 122.04H254.428C254.428 95.3746 228.038 77.901 201.415 77.8869C197.542 77.8755 193.678 78.2513 189.881 79.0085C185.606 79.8621 181.169 80.885 176.809 82.2182C159.618 87.4879 143.675 97.6743 143.675 122.04C143.671 126.772 144.273 131.485 145.467 136.064L142.052 136.953C140.786 132.083 140.146 127.072 140.148 122.04C140.148 100.75 148.888 86.1264 163.984 77.4072C171.92 72.8218 181.606 69.8661 192.702 68.427C197.32 67.8127 201.988 67.6708 206.635 68.0037C237.251 70.2047 257.955 93.6816 257.955 122.04Z" fill="#009B77"/>
        <path id="Vector_43" d="M263.832 123.994L262.442 113.723C262.099 111.129 260.85 108.74 258.915 106.979C257.673 105.831 256.186 104.98 254.566 104.491C252.947 104.003 251.238 103.888 249.568 104.157L247.36 104.461C246.755 104.54 246.173 104.739 245.646 105.045C245.12 105.352 244.659 105.76 244.291 106.245C243.92 106.73 243.649 107.282 243.492 107.872C243.336 108.462 243.298 109.076 243.381 109.681L246.591 133.341C246.723 134.305 247.155 135.204 247.826 135.909C248.497 136.614 249.373 137.09 250.33 137.27C250.613 137.327 250.901 137.356 251.19 137.355C251.398 137.355 251.605 137.341 251.811 137.313L254.28 136.981C255.785 136.781 257.234 136.276 258.537 135.496C259.84 134.716 260.969 133.678 261.856 132.445C262.047 132.177 262.23 131.902 262.4 131.62C263.722 129.312 264.226 126.625 263.832 123.994Z" fill="#009B77"/>
        <path id="Vector_44" d="M245.935 104.891C245.287 105.206 244.724 105.67 244.291 106.245C243.92 106.73 243.649 107.282 243.492 107.872C243.336 108.462 243.298 109.076 243.381 109.681L246.591 133.341C246.723 134.306 247.155 135.204 247.826 135.909C248.497 136.614 249.373 137.09 250.33 137.27L245.935 104.891Z" fill="white"/>
        <path id="Vector_45" d="M263.832 123.994L262.442 113.723C262.099 111.129 260.85 108.74 258.915 106.979L262.11 130.519C262.158 130.897 262.255 131.267 262.4 131.62C263.722 129.312 264.226 126.625 263.832 123.994Z" fill="#3F3D56"/>
        <path id="Vector_46" d="M252.848 131.395C253.813 131.264 254.299 128.967 253.932 126.264C253.565 123.562 252.486 121.477 251.521 121.608C250.555 121.739 250.07 124.036 250.437 126.738C250.803 129.441 251.883 131.526 252.848 131.395Z" fill="#3F3D56"/>
        <path id="Vector_47" d="M250.732 118.697C251.697 118.566 252.182 116.269 251.816 113.566C251.449 110.864 250.369 108.779 249.404 108.91C248.439 109.041 247.954 111.338 248.32 114.041C248.687 116.743 249.767 118.828 250.732 118.697Z" fill="#3F3D56"/>
        <path id="Vector_48" d="M264.135 123.635C265.1 123.504 265.586 121.207 265.219 118.505C264.852 115.802 263.773 113.717 262.808 113.848C261.842 113.979 261.357 116.276 261.724 118.979C262.09 121.681 263.17 123.766 264.135 123.635Z" fill="#3F3D56"/>
        <path id="Vector_49" d="M201.415 77.8868C197.542 77.8755 193.678 78.2513 189.881 79.0085C185.606 79.8621 181.169 80.8849 176.809 82.2182C170.002 81.8867 164.993 80.1231 163.984 77.4071C171.92 72.8218 181.606 69.866 192.702 68.4269C197.32 67.8126 201.988 67.6708 206.635 68.0037C207.127 68.292 207.552 68.6812 207.883 69.1457C208.213 69.6101 208.442 70.1393 208.554 70.6984C208.885 73.1534 206.085 75.7635 201.415 77.8868Z" fill="#3F3D56"/>
        <path id="Vector_50" d="M156.38 146.519L150.948 123.938C150.754 123.123 150.324 122.384 149.711 121.813C149.099 121.242 148.331 120.864 147.505 120.728C147.272 120.692 147.036 120.673 146.8 120.672C146.467 120.673 146.136 120.713 145.812 120.791L143.71 121.299C141.003 121.954 138.667 123.656 137.213 126.031C135.76 128.406 135.308 131.261 135.957 133.969L138.391 144.099C138.947 146.484 140.27 148.62 142.158 150.18C142.464 150.427 142.784 150.655 143.117 150.864C144.3 151.605 145.619 152.102 146.996 152.325C148.374 152.548 149.782 152.493 151.138 152.162L153.233 151.654C153.787 151.525 154.309 151.282 154.764 150.942C155.442 150.448 155.957 149.764 156.245 148.976C156.532 148.188 156.579 147.333 156.38 146.519Z" fill="#009B77"/>
        <path id="Vector_51" d="M144.992 142.317C145.939 142.089 146.19 139.755 145.552 137.104C144.914 134.452 143.629 132.487 142.682 132.715C141.735 132.943 141.484 135.277 142.122 137.929C142.76 140.58 144.045 142.545 144.992 142.317Z" fill="#3F3D56"/>
        <path id="Vector_52" d="M137.938 144.434C138.885 144.206 139.135 141.871 138.497 139.22C137.859 136.568 136.574 134.604 135.627 134.832C134.68 135.059 134.43 137.394 135.068 140.045C135.706 142.697 136.991 144.661 137.938 144.434Z" fill="#3F3D56"/>
        <path id="Vector_53" d="M156.725 146.434L151.293 123.853C151.082 122.972 150.615 122.172 149.951 121.555C149.287 120.937 148.456 120.53 147.562 120.382L154.976 151.224C155.708 150.688 156.265 149.947 156.576 149.094C156.888 148.242 156.94 147.316 156.725 146.434Z" fill="white"/>
        <path id="Vector_54" d="M137.185 129.497C137.035 128.869 136.753 128.28 136.359 127.768C135.596 129.746 135.455 131.909 135.957 133.969L138.391 144.099C138.947 146.484 140.27 148.62 142.158 150.18L137.185 129.497Z" fill="#3F3D56"/>
        </g>
        </g>
        <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip0_3_67">
        <rect width="600" height="522.608" fill="white"/>
        </clipPath>
        </defs>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have `rotateZ('-10deg');` Remove the quotes around the degs: `rotateZ(-10deg);`

Comment: @enxaneta Yeah, you are right, thank you. I used emmet in VSCode and I forgot to remove quotes.